# [Wordpress]Regex on searchform

Tags: regex, wordpress

I have to tweak the searchform from my wordpress theme, because it wont allows me to use accents such as é/è/à/ù etc, I dont to make them non-special chars and I thought about using Regex but cant figure out how/where to put the regex snippet.

Here is the page code :

```
do_action( 'mytheme_before_searchform' ); ?>
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">
<div class="row collapse">
    <?php do_action( 'mytheme_searchform_top' ); ?>
    <div class="small-11 columns">
        <input type="text" value="" class="search-form" name="s" id="s" placeholder="SEARCH">
    </div>
    <?php do_action( 'mytheme_searchform_before_search_button' ); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'mytheme_searchform_after_search_button' ); ?>
</div>
```

Any idea how I should proceed ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it on your theme's function file. In my case the form is redirected to the wp page /google-search (permalink), like this:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
$aNewRules = array('google-search/([^/]+)/?$' => 'google-search?pagename=page-google-search&q=$matches[1]');
$aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
return $aRules;
```

}

And i have registered the q var so wp allows it to be passed on the url.
Hope this help!